# MySQL - Get row # of total results

Tags: mysql

I have a table listing items for which I wish to get the row/record # from the total amount returned.

| id | name | group | date_added |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | john | 123 | 2021-05-01 |
| 22 | joe | 123 | 2021-05-03 |
| 33 | mike | 123 | 2021-05-05 |
| 44 | ed | 123 | 2021-05-15 |

Trying to make a query that returns the row # of "mike" out of the entire group. Which would be #3.

Comment: @Akina just edited to say order it by date added.

Comment: `SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date_added) rownumber FROM tablename`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use window function :

```
select * from (
  select * , row_number() over (order by date_added) rn 
  from table 
) t
where name = 'mike'
```